# Wordpress - I can reach by url normal php files but no uploaded ones

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress project, and I'm trying to create a product via woocommerce rest API, I made it work in local, but when I upload the files to the server, I just can't reach via URL my file, for example,
If I write:

```
    $.get('http://example.com/wp-includes/option.php')
    .done(function() {
        alert('Correct');
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Nope');
})
```

An alert with Correct appears, but, if I write:

```
    $.get('http://example.com/wp-includes/createProduct.php')
    .done(function() {
        alert('Correct');
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Nope');
})
```

An alert with Nope will be shown, so I don't get why it reaches all its 'native' files and not that one I uploaded. Files like .js in the js folder are being read correctly, but this .php just can't be reached. And I need it for an AJAX :c

Hope someone can help me and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory/file permissions.

On linux try running ll -h inside the wp-includes directory to compare the user and read/write permissions of the files being created.

For instance, you may be user ubuntu, ec2-user, something like that, but your files are being created and owned by root.

EDIT:

Upload your files through cpanel's file manager.

Whether I upload the file using winscp or cpanel file manager, it doesn't affect the read/write permissions, it's always 0644, which should work.  BUT uploading through cpanel's file manager, the ownership for the file is the same where as using winscp to upload the user is different.

Comment: This would make a better comment than an answer

Comment: Okay, @j08691, a rephrase might help.

Comment: Ok... so I don't get it pretty well, sorry :/ I'm pretty new at Wordpress and CPanels world, I don't have a linux at hand, but I cheked and it has read permissions, I'm not trying to create a file, just to read a file uploaded from FTP (Sorry if I didnt explained correctly), It has the same level of permissions than option.php, and still nothing :/

Comment: @ErickRosas I've updated my answer based on your comments.  Your permissions may be correct but it sounds like it might be an ownership issue.  For one particular site I have, uploading through winscp uses a different user than the site uses, but cpanel uses the same user.  So, anything I upload through winscp, I have to change the ownership of before the site can access it.  This might be your issue, so if you're uploading using an ftp client like winscp/filezilla/cuteftp, try the cpanel file manager instead.